# How to decide which velocity is bigger in a collision before writing velocity of approach and velocity of separation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, velocity, relative-motion

My teacher said that velocity of separation is $V_1$- $V_2$ where $V_1$ is greater than $V_2$ and said same for velocity of approach. The problem is how would you determine which velocity is greater if the question requires you to find an unknown velocity . We can make mistakes in writing correct equations.

Hope you got my point :)

Comment: I guess you are talking about collisions and stuff, to select which one is bigger and so that we can write conservation of momentum?

Comment: yes that is what i meant

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image]

The trick here is to use relative velocity of approach= negative relative velocity of seperation. By defining a specific direction to be positive and then assigning a direction(sign) to every velocity, all u need to do is plug in the **signed** velocities into the vector equation

I have given the derivation of the formula below with velocities of completely arbitrarily direction ( the vector sign shows that the direction can be anything even in 3d space!). I must admit that I just added the vector signs in the k.e equation instead or doing it the right way using manipulation of the dot product, but that will just confuse u.

This shows that one u have chosen a specific direction to ge positive, just use the momentum and reltive velocity equations in **vector** form

I have included a solved example using vectors, which just take care of themselves without you having to worry about keeping anything  positive

[image]

Comment: Please do not post scanned or photographed formulas or derivations. They are search engine unfriendly.

Comment: Oooopsie: *They are not search engine unfriendly*, of course!

Comment: OVERWOOTCH , your answer is good but the way you wrote COM looks like Centre Of Mass rather than Conservation Of Momentum

Comment: I’m sorry, I was kinda in a hurry. Also, i posted a scanned picture because I don't know how to format. But it’s nice being downvoted for no reason at all and apparently being discouraged to answer questions if I do not know How to format.

Comment: Give me some time I will convert your images to mathjax.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity of approach is the velocity with which two bodies are approaching each other or say the velocity with which the distance between the two bodies is decreasing or the velocity of body A as seen from body B or vice versa.

[image]

In the above picture for the two bodies to collide $U_1$ must be greater than $U_2$. So here we can surely say which body has a greater speed.

[image]

The above picture shows the scenario after collision. So after collision the bodies tend to go apart and the velocity with which their separation increases is called the velocity of separation. Here you can apply some common sense that if the speed $V_2$ is less than $V_1$ then they will collide again but for only one collision, $V_2$ must be greater than $V_1$  and only in this case the two bodies will separate.

**Note**: The sense in which the term $V_1$ and $V_2$ is used  in your question might not be the same as used in my answer. So refer to the image for better understanding.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether the particles will collide once or more than one times (before calculating velocities of course)

Comment: @Aryaman I don't think there is a way to determine that. Maybe there exists a way but I am not aware of that. Sorry for your inconvenience .

Comment: @Aryaman was the answer helpful ?

Comment: yes it was helpful, thanks

Comment: @ankit that is extremely wrong. V2 cant be less than V1. At some point in the collision, the two masses are moving at the same velocity, after which the 2nd mass either speeds up (fully/partially elastic) or they both stick(inelastic). It is common sense that the 2 masses cant even separate if V2<V1.

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH i think you didn't understand whati wrote. I said that **if** $V_2$ is less than $V_1$  then they will collide again.  I know it is not possible but i just tried to explain him what is collision.